# Should we use ICollection<T> in the Interface and Collection<T> in the class?

Tags: c#, collections

I have an interface and a class that implements it. Now I want to keep a collection of some things in this class.
Sholud I use **ICollection** in its **interface** part and use **Collection** in the concerete **class** part?

Is it a better practice and more flexible to use ICollection in both parts?

Also: the "things" that I said I want to keep a collection of them in my class, they are also objects of some other classes I have and those classes again have their own interfacs. So what is the best pracitce? should I even use the interface type of these clases when I want to save them in the collection?

Comment: I would initialize it as something like `ICollection<Foo> bar = new List<Foo>(); ...` and then use `ICollection<Foo>` from there on (inside and outside of the class). Hopefully I understood the question correctly. Note that `ICollection<Foo>` might be too primitive for your needs and so an `IList<Foo>` would work better instead. This is something that I ended up doing once - switching from `ICollection` to `IList` since I needed to have the order as opposed to using something as general as a set.

Comment: yes, you understood it correctly..just for the second part of my question: do you recommned ICollection<Foo>  or to use ICollection<IFoo>  ... the interface of Foo class

Comment: Try to remain practical. If you do plan on changing the behavior of what implements `IFoo` and substitute a different thing, then yes, you do need an `IFoo` (and I hope that C# is smart enough to recognize the equivalence; I have not tried it). If you do not need to change the implementation of `Foo`, then there is probably not a good reason to create an `IFoo`. With `ICollection<Foo>` it makes more sense - you want to have the ability to use different data structures, say if you suddenly need better performance. You could substitute say dequee in place of List and still be good

Comment: hmm, Order?  oh wait! so the things I add to Collection if I later do a ForEach loop on them they won't show up on the smae order that have been added to the collection?  Do we have some sort of OrderredCollection maybe ?

Comment: yes, there is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee211538.aspx. You have to ask yourself what your real needs are. I realized that I started to go out of my way to support with an `ICollection`, but then realized that all I need is to support  an array and a list `95%` of the time. The other 5% of the time I could call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`; I could afford the cost of doing that. This worked conveniently well with the one of the C#'s coolest feature: `params T[]`. I never ended up needing an `OrderedSet`, but only you know best what your problem (will) demands.

Comment: @Leonid : Thank you very much Sir for your patience and information. I learned a lot. Sorry your answers were in the comments so I just colud up-vote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can expose an interface rather than a class, expose the interface; expose the class only if you must do so, for example, to expose methods not available on the interface. You should do it both in your interface and in your class.

The rationale is that information hiding is a *"good thing"*, so if you can do it without losing of generality, you should do so.

Comment: thanks, so in @Lenoids example, do you recommend ICollection<Foo> or do you recommned ICollection<IFoo> ? ( interface of Foo)

Comment: Exposing the interface gives you the added option of swapping in a different implementation or mock

Comment: @DarkNightFan I do not think it is possible to assign `List<Foo>` to `IList<IFoo>` ([link](http://ideone.com/HxH2d) to ideone with compilation error), so you would need to use `IList<Foo>`.